# NativeBase - Button dimmed onPress

Tags: react-native, button, native-base

I'm using `Button` component from `NativeBase`, is there any way to giving feedback that showing user has pressed the button like `TouchableOpactiy` does?

Comment: Maybe you could try wrapping button by [TouchableHighlight tag](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight.html)?